# Словообразование

Tags: словообразование, приставка, суффиксы

Какими способами образованы слова-АНТИЦИКЛОН,НАСТОЛЬНЫЙ,РАЗГРУЗКА?Я думаю что так-приставочный,приставочно-суффиксальный,приставочно-суффиксальный.

Answer (score 3):

> Какими способами образованы слова
> АНТИЦИКЛОН, НАСТОЛЬНЫЙ, РАЗГРУЗКА?  Я
> думаю, что так: приставочный,
> приставочно-суффиксальный,
> приставочно-суффиксальный.

АНТИЦИКЛОН -- да, приставочный: циклон -> **анти**-циклон.

НАСТОЛЬНЫЙ -- да, приставочно-суффиксальный: стол -> **на**-столь-**н**-ый.

РАЗГРУЗКА -- суффиксальный: (груз -> грузить ->) разгрузить -> разгруз-**к**-а.

Comment: Спасибо!!!